# Appending text to a line in a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Is there a way to append text to the last line in a ListBox? I'd like a listing to look like this:

```
processing file 1...  OK
processing file 2...  CRC error
processing file 3...  OK
```

When I open the file for processing, I would write "processing file x" with ListBox.Add("processing file x"). When done processing, before moving on to the next file, I would like to append the processing results.

I could wait until processing is complete, and just write the whole line at once, but it can take 10-15 seconds to process a file and it makes the UI look unresponsive.

A solution would also let me append text like (% complete) or something to make the UI more active while processing.  I prefer to do this with a ListBox because of its scrolling and line selection properties, if possible.

I've not been able to find any way to do this; any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: What is your code that updates the ListBox? This seems a job to be done by a BackgroundWorker that after each file is processed notifies the UI thread of the work in progress. But if your whole process is executed in a single method of the UI thread then you need to wait the end of the method to have the UI updated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you seem to want a couple things: A way for your program to update a `ListBox` in the background as it processes a file and possible a way to edit the line of the `ListBox` rather than adding a new line to show this new status update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly add items to the list box

```
 listBox1.Items.Add("new item");
```

and you may need to refresh it

```
listBox1.Refresh();
```

Edit :

In case you want to update the last item, you need to remove the last item and then re add it

```
var lastItem= listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count-1];
lastItem += results;
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.Items.Count-1);
listBox1.Add(lastItem);
```

Comment: OP already has items in the `ListBox`, so I don't think this addresses the problem they are having.

Comment: did not notice that , Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a GUI event is processed on the same thread as the GUI rendering, so the UI will be unresponsive until it's done.

The quick and hacky solution is to just call [Application.DoEvents()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) after each ListBox.Add call. The form will still be jittery if you try to drag it around, but that function will cause the GUI to update/render once.

The *correct* way to do it is to use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx), which you can start from the GUI event and will process in the background on a separate thread. If you implement its ProgressChanged function, you can call this from DoWork:

```
(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i/(float)totalFiles,msgString)
```

And then in ProgressChanged, do your whole:

```
listBox.Add(e.UserState.ToString() + ", " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "% completed.")
```

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` isn't the **correct** way to do it, but it is however one of the easiest.

Comment: @Cameron What do you think is the "correct"/"best" way to do it, within the sphere of WinForms?

Comment: My favorite answer... "It depends." BackgroundWorker makes things easy within the sphere of WinForms, but I'd much rather take my business logic (which is what this is), and my threading to something that isn't so coupled with WinForms. And I like more fine-grained control of multi-threaded stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

```
var i = listBox.Items.Count - 1;  // crash bug if there is no line to append to
listBox.Items[i] = listBox.Items[i] + message;
```

Or, for a more complete solution (works from a non UI thread):

```
public static class Util
{
    public static async Task RunOnUiThread(Action a)
    {
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { a(); });
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private async Task Write(string message)
    {
        var action = new Action(() =>
        {
            var i = OutputListBox.Items.Count - 1;
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                OutputListBox.Items[i] = OutputListBox.Items[i] + message;
            }
            else
            {
                OutputListBox.Items.Add(message);
            }
        });

        await Util.RunOnUiThread(action);
    }
}
```